# References within references / Citations within citations

Tags: bibliographies, citing

In academic writing its occasionally desirable to draw attention to the references within another paper, as well as referencing the paper itself. To do this I would write [*Author*, *Year*, **and refs. within**].

But this, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This guy reviewed it all before (\cite{lamport94} and refs. within)
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{lamport94}
Bob Smith,
The review of everything.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

gives:

*This guy said it all before ([1] and refs. within)*

But I want "and refs. within" to appear in the same (single) bracket as the reference.

How can I do this in Latex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have done so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need

```
\cite[and refs. within]{lamport94}
```

complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This guy reviewed it all before \cite[and refs. within]{lamport94} 
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{lamport94}
Bob Smith,
The review of everything.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```